# Location of Windows video memory

Tags: windows, dma

I'm currently analyzing a KVM solution. For this purpose I would like to locate the Windows video memory which is used by the KVM probably using DMA. Is there a way to achieve this?

The system is currently running Windows Server 2016.
The system got no graphics card so the memory should reside whthin the RAM or not?

Comment: If you have no graphics card then how would you have actual video RAM? Please explain exactly what you have setup and what you are expecting to see or do.

Comment: My guess was that on systems without a video card the video controller chip (VCC) is connected to the RAM to store pixel data, so you can call this  section of RAM "video memory". The KVM solution can access this data using the VCC to compress it and send it over the network. In my case we are talking about a server including a integrated KVM solution packed together with the out of band management.

Comment: You mean you have *integrated* graphics, not no graphics.  IIRC, if you run regedit32 and navigate to the correct location in the hardware registry, you can see what resources are allocated to the hardware.  Also probably in device manager these days.